# Загрузка большого количества картинок в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго, комрады, посоветуйте как лучше построить логику (если можно с примерами).

**Дано**: путь к директории. Надо отобразить в `ListBox` (или любой другой подобный компонент, если в другой будет проще и легче) изображения из этой директории.

**Проблемы**: не все изображения имеют миниатюры, это раз. Изображения могут быть большими (до 20 мб) и их может быть с сотню. Как сделать так что бы это все не вешало приложение при загрузке.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, чтение файловой системы обязательно должно происходить в отдельном потоке или через async/await. Многочисленные примеры в интернете грешат чтением данных в главном потоке (и чуть ли не в `OnClick`).

Для начала, разделите UI и логику. В UI просто забиндьтесь к `ObservableCollection<ImageVM>`, и спокойно грузите картинки в фоне.

Для VM-части, для начала коллекция пуста. Обойдите в отдельном thread-pool-потоке каталог:

```
var imageFiles = await Task.Run(() => Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg"));
foreach (var f in imageFiles)
{
    BitmapImage img = await Task.Run(() => LoadImage(f));
    ImageVM imageVM = new ImageVM(img);
    ImageCollection.Add(imageVM);
}
```

Здесь код `LoadImage` должен асинхронно загрузить картинку или создать миниатюру. Например (это *без* проверки размера):

```
BitmapImage LoadImage(string path)
{
    BitmapImage s = new BitmapImage();
    s.BeginInit();
    s.UriSource = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(path));
    s.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    s.EndInit();
    s.Freeze();
    return s;
}
```

Если картинок много, и сам список не «летает» *после* загрузки, используйте [виртуализацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.isvirtualizing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

Альтернативным решением может быть использование [`PriorityBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Насколько понимаю, это net 4.5? А младше только PriorityBinding?

Comment: @Виктор: Да, это 4.5. Для младших версий я бы использовал `BackgroundWorker` для чтения картинок и доставки их по одной в основной поток.

Comment: @Виктор: И не забудьте уменьшить изображения до нормального размера! А то 100 огромных картинок переполнят память.

Comment: Благодарю, это помогло.